# How to search by multiple columns?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot and hibernate. I have the following table:

```
firstName |  lastName | department(FK) | city
```

So far, I was successful in finding records by department (FK) with the following in my repository:

```
List<User> findByDepartmentId(@Param(value = "department") Long department);
```

Now, I would like to find not only by department, but also by city (which is a string value). How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `And` in your method name (assuming you are using `spring-data-jpa` and `city` is the name of the field in your model),

```
List<User> findByDepartmentIdAndCity(Long id, String city);
```